# Place input next to icon

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want to to add an eye on my bootstrap input as:

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="current">Current Password</label>
  <input asp-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
  <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="password-addon" tabindex="99"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
  <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question and add in your query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain what results it's giving you. So far, we only know the expected results... Which does not help us identify the issue you're encountering with your query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout input group, button addons: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/input-group/#button-addons

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mb-3">
  <label class="form-label" for="current">Current Password</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input asp-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
    <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="password-addon" tabindex="99"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
  </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by bootstrap Input Group. See the example below.

For more details:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label" for="current">Current Password</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <input asp-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="form-control" required autofocus />
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button class="btn btn-light shadow-none ms-0" type="button" id="password-addon" tabindex="99"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  <span asp-validation-for="ChangePassword.OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```